# using netbeans with zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a project and a controller called about.

But I dont know how to navigate from the controller to my webpage...

Even when I write the url, the website doesnt appear :(

```
http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/About
```

Comment: Too little information. Please at least tell us where your application sources are located and how your webserver is configured.

Comment: are you using XAMPP or Apache ? Is your project in the correct folder 'htdocs' ?

Answer (score 0):

default url structure `http://host/controller/action`, I'm familiar with this book so assuming everything is properly setup try `http://localhost/dev.gamenomad.com/about/contact` the url you're calling will by default load the indexAction and I don't think you have one yet.

Also in your netbeans right click on your project name, then at the bottom of the menu select properties, then in the left pane select 'Run Configuration'. Now make sure your *Project url* is correct and if you have specified an *Index file* make sure it points to *public/Index.php* (usually when using Zend Framework I don't specify an Index file)

Now if you still have issues go through the checklist:

- mod_rewrite enabled in httpd.conf (or in .htaccess)
- vhost setup and enabled if using one
- make sure there is an .htaccess in your */public* folder (put there by Zend_Tool when building app).
- you're not using Internet Explorer (This browser give strange behavior, especially for newbies)
- enable development mode or changed all the 0 in your *application.ini* to 1